# Why is typename required in front of template function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm using an example from Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed Page 692.  Does anyone know why `typename` must come before `Iter::value_type`?  Specifically in relation to the second `mean` function, why is `typename` not required for this template function?

I have read through Stroustrup's book sequentially and am in the templates section.  I do not recall reading about the reasoning behind this.

Thanks for your guidance!

```
template<typename Iter>
typename Iter::value_type mean(Iter first, Iter last);

template<typename T>
T mean(T*,T*);

void f(vector<int>& v, int* p, int n)
{
    auto x = mean(v.begin(),v.end());
    auto y = mean(p,p+n);
}
```

Comment: In the 1st `mean()`, the `Iter::value_type` is *dependent* on what `Iter` is set to. The `value_type` could be a type, a constant, a member function, etc. So the extra `typename` is needed to let the compiler know that `value_type` is guaranteed to be a type, even when the type of `Iter` is not known yet.  In the 2nd `mean()`, the compiler already knows that `T` is a type.

Comment: Note that this has changed in c++20. You no longer need `typename` for this example.